# Loud vibrating when using hot water!

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater

I recently moved into a new condo with 2 kitchen sinks -- a main one and one embedded in an island.  There's a lot going on under the main one -- the cold water is split so that it leads to the faucet and the fridge, hot water split to lead to the faucet and the dishwasher.

When I turn on the hot water all the way (so there's no cold water coming out at all) the valve under the sink starts to vibrate very loudly.  It sounds like a bad muffler!  And if I open up the doors under the sink I can see it vibrate very quickly.  It's hard to tell if the noise is coming from the water heater (which is right next to the kitchen) or the valve itself or maybe both.  If I twist the handle slightly to let some cold water out of the faucet too, then the vibrating and noise stop.

This does not happen on the other sink (which is on an island and has its own line).

Any idea why this might happen and want I can do to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely due to a partially closed shutoff valve under your sink. Most such valves are designed to stop water but not to just reduce the flow, so if the valve isn't fully opened, it may be partially obstructing the water flow in a way that generates lots of noise/vibration. So check the valves supplying hot water to your sink and make sure they're completely opened.

Comment: that seems to have fixed it, thanks!  the water was coming out strong enough that I guess I didn't even think that was the problem.